# Extracting Junction point in skeleton

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently working with opencv and c++ in project at school . My problem is how to extract junction point in a skeleton image . I have tried to develop this code but it doesn't work and I didn't find the mistake . Thanks in advance .

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("IMG.jpg",0);
if (im.empty())
    return -1;
cv::Mat img_rgb(im.size(), CV_8UC3);
cv::threshold(img_rgb, img_rgb, 155, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cv::cvtColor(im, img_rgb, CV_GRAY2RGB);

int s=0;

    for (int i = 1; i < img_rgb.rows-1; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 1; j < img_rgb.cols-1; j++)
    {

    if(255 == img_rgb.at<uchar>(i,j))
    {
        uchar p1 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i, j);
        uchar p2 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i-1, j);
        uchar p3 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i-1, j+1);
        uchar p4 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i, j+1);
        uchar p5 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i+1, j+1);
        uchar p6 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i+1, j);
        uchar p7 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i+1, j-1);
        uchar p8 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i, j-1);
        uchar p9 = img_rgb.at<uchar>(i-1, j-1);
       // s = abs(p9-p8)+abs(p8-p7)+abs(p7-p6)+abs(p6-p5)+abs(p5-p4)+abs(p4-p3)+abs(p3-p2)+abs(p2-p9);
        //    if (s == 1530)

                int same=(p9==p1);
                 same+=(p8==p1);
                same+=(p7==p1);
                 same+=(p6==p1);
                 same+=(p5==p1);
                 same+=(p4==p1);
                 same+=(p3==p1);
                 same+=(p2==p1);
              if (same==2)
              {


        //                   cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" " <<same<<endl;
    circle(img_rgb,Point(i,j),1,Scalar(0, 255, 0),1);
            }

    }
    }
}

cv::imshow("a",img_rgb);
cv::waitKey();

return 0 ;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're thresholding img_rgb, which is empty at that moment.

also, why the conversion from gray to rgb, again ?
(btw, if you loop over a rgb image, `mat.at<uchar>(y,x)` is wrong, should be `mat.at<Vec3b>(y,x)` )

i'd say, skip the gray2rgb conversion, and instead threshold the grayscale image loaded:

```
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("IMG.jpg",0);
if (im.empty())
    return -1;

cv::Mat thresh;
cv::threshold(im, thresh, 155, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

and then use that mat for further processing:

```
for (int i = 1; i < thresh.rows-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < thresh.cols-1; j++)
    {
        uchar p1 = thresh.at<uchar>(i, j);
        if(255 == p1)
        {   
             uchar p2 = thresh.at<uchar>(i-1, j);
             uchar p3 = thresh.at<uchar>(i-1, j+1);

             // ...
```